# Can I switch to Consolas for \texttt?

Tags: fonts, typewriter

For part of my documentation I want my \texttt to use a fixed-spacing font that slashes its zeroes.  The default font LaTeX uses for the purpose (Courier New, I suppose) does not.  I'm used to Consolas for this purpose, but I don't suppose it matters much.  How do I set the default tt font?

(I looked up this question and found a reference to \setmonofont, but \setmonofont{Consolas} generates an error message about an undefined control sequence; I suspect \setmonofont is for lua only.)

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! I think most monospaced fonts let you choose whether or not you use slashed zeroes. It is usually an available OpenType feature.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`inconsolata`](https://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\begin{document}
\texttt{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, that looks good!  Only one problem: It doesn't respond to \textit, which I need to use for variables.  Sigh.  (But thanks anyway.)

Comment: Is your text in math mode? If so, try `\mathit`.

Comment: You can also try the [iosevka](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka) font with lualatex (be warned, that font is a monster. Expect a lot of delay the first time you compile to build the caches...)

Answer (score 4):

The `\setmonofont` command works in either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX if you

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

You probably want

```
\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

or possibly

```
\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

But be aware, Consolas is not a free font.  If you do this, other people will only be able to recompile your document from source on a machine with Microsoft Windows or Microsoft Office installed.

Answer (score 4):

As illustration of using OTF font features with `fontspec`, TeX Gyre Cursor font is a fixed-width font which has the slashed-zero OpenType font feature.

[image: TexGyreCursor]

You can use any suitable font instead.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Tex Gyre Cursor}[Numbers=SlashedZero]
\newfontfamily\fontcons{Tex Gyre Cursor}[Numbers=SlashedZero]

\newcommand\digits{0123456789}
\newcommand\sample[1]{{\fontcons#1abc \digits\ xyz iiii mmmm}}

\begin{document}
As document mono-spaced font: 

\texttt{\digits}

\texttt{\textit{\digits}}

\texttt{\textbf{\digits}}

\texttt{\textit{\textbf{\digits}}}

\bigskip
As custom font family

A. \sample{}

B. \sample{\itshape}

C. \sample{\bfseries}

D. \sample{\itshape\bfseries}

\end{document}
```